# Split a Polygon that Crosses International Date Line, ArcPy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system

I have a lots of existing data in WGS-1984 (too much to manually edit).  I need to split these lines and polygons by the international date line.

More projection information:
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

Sample Coordinates:
([170, 0], [-170, 0], [-170, 10], [170, 10], [170, 0])

Does anyone have any python code to do this?

For regular polygons like this square it would be easy to detect if the vertical line crossing -180 (anti-meridian), but most polygons aren't nice squares.  So if I could give a set of points and detect and split the polygon into a multipart polygon would be what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Have you tried Intersect (Analysis)?

Comment: Intersect does not work because ArcPy draws the points in the wrong order.

Comment: Can you edit your Question to include the following details, please?  What is the precise coordinate system(s) of this data?  You say its datum is WGS 1984 but including the full *.prj file name(s) would be more helpful so that we know whether code needs to deal with Geographic and/or Projected Coordinate Systems.   Is your data global?  Do you have an existing feature class that includes the International Date Line?  If so, is it a line or polygon feature class? Can you explain more about what does not work when you use Intersect?

Comment: Add more information.

Comment: The International Date Line does not follow -180 all the way: http://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/infopage/dateline.htm

Comment: I know, so I guess I need to modify it to say I need to split data on the line -180

Comment: What version of ArcGIS do you use?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.2.2 Info

Comment: @PolyGeo: I think he is referring to the Prime Meridian Crossover Bug

Comment: @thenonhacker Can you provide a link to the "Prime Meridian Crossover Bug", please?  My quick Google just now turned up nothing on it.

Comment: On Google Earth they call it "Midway Bug"
https://code.google.com/p/earth-issues/issues/detail?id=8